# Tidymodels: Decision Tree Learning in R - Error: No variables or terms were selected

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, prediction, tidymodels

**Overview:**

I have a data frame called 'FID'and I am attempting to follow this tutorial (see below) to produce three models: **(1) Bagged trees; (2) Random Forests; and (3) Boosted Trees.**

**Tutorial:**

https://bcullen.rbind.io/post/2020-06-02-tidymodels-decision-tree-learning-in-r/

**Issue**

when I try to run the models, **"fit_bag"**, **fit_rf**, **"fit_boost"**, I am experiencing this error message below. I think the issue may lie in the pre-processing phase.

Would anyone be able to help advise with this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

**Error - no variables are selected**

```
i Fold01: recipe
x Fold01: recipe: Error: No variables or terms were selected.
i Fold02: recipe
x Fold02: recipe: Error: No variables or terms were selected.
i Fold03: recipe
x Fold03: recipe: Error: No variables or terms were selected.
i Fold04: recipe
x Fold04: recipe: Error: No variables or terms were selected.
i Fold05: recipe
x Fold05: recipe: Error: No variables or terms were selected.
i Fold06: recipe
x Fold06: recipe: Error: No variables or terms were selected.
i Fold07: recipe
x Fold07: recipe: Error: No variables or terms were selected.
i Fold08: recipe
x Fold08: recipe: Error: No variables or terms were selected.
i Fold09: recipe
x Fold09: recipe: Error: No variables or terms were selected.
i Fold10: recipe
x Fold10: recipe: Error: No variables or terms were selected.
Warning message:
All models failed in [fit_resamples()]. See the `.notes` column.
```

**R-code**

```
    ##Open library packages
    library(tidymodels) 
    library(tidyverse) # manipulating data
    library(skimr) # data visualization
    library(baguette) # bagged trees
    library(future) # parallel processing & decrease computation time
    library(xgboost) # boosted trees
    
    # split the data
    split <- initial_split(Tidmodel_df)
    
    # extract the training data
    train <- training(split)
    
    # resample the data with 10-fold cross-validation (10-fold by default)
    cv <- vfold_cv(train)
    
##Preprocessing

rec <- recipe(Frequency~., data=train) %>% 
       update_role(contains("id"), Year, Month, Monsoon, Days, new_role = "id vars") %>% # declare ID variables
       step_nzv(all_predictors(), freq_cut = 0, unique_cut = 0) %>% # remove variables with zero variances
       step_novel(all_nominal()) %>% # prepares test data to handle previously unseen factor levels 
       step_medianimpute(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes(), -has_role("id vars"))  %>% # replaces missing numeric observations with the median
       step_dummy(all_nominal(), -has_role("id vars")) # dummy codes categorical variables
    
    ###########################################################
    ##Create Models
    ###########################################################

    #####Bagged Trees
    mod_bag <- bag_tree() %>%
                set_mode("regression") %>%
                 set_engine("rpart", times = 10) # 10 bootstrap resamples
    
    ##Create workflow
    wflow_bag <- workflow() %>% 
                       add_recipe(rec) %>%
                           add_model(mod_bag)
    
    ##Fit the model
    plan(multisession)
    
    fit_bag <- fit_resamples(
                       wflow_bag,
                       cv,
                       metrics = metric_set(rmse, rsq),
                       control = control_resamples(verbose = TRUE,
                       save_pred = TRUE,
                       extract = function(x) extract_model(x)))
    
    ##Random forests
    
    mod_rf <-rand_forest() %>%
                          set_engine("ranger",
                          num.threads = parallel::detectCores(), 
                          importance = "permutation", 
                          verbose = TRUE) %>% 
                          set_mode("regression") %>% 
                          set_args(trees = 1000)
    
    ##Create Workflow
    
    wflow_rf <- workflow() %>% 
                   add_model(mod_rf) %>% 
                         add_recipe(rec)
    
    ##Fit the model
    
    plan(multisession)
    
    fit_rf <- fit_resamples(
                         wflow_rf,
                         cv,
                         metrics = metric_set(rmse, rsq),
                         control = control_resamples(verbose = TRUE,
                         save_pred = TRUE,
                         extract = function(x) x)
                         )
    
    ##Boosted Trees
    
    mod_boost <- boost_tree() %>% 
                  set_engine("xgboost", nthreads = parallel::detectCores()) %>% 
                  set_mode("regression")
    
    ##Create workflow
    
    wflow_boost <- workflow() %>% 
                      add_recipe(rec) %>% 
                      add_model(mod_boost)
    
    ##Fit model
    
    plan(multisession)
    
    fit_boost <- fit_resamples(
                           wflow_boost, 
                           cv,
                           metrics = metric_set(rmse, rsq),
                           control = control_resamples(verbose = TRUE,
                           save_pred = TRUE)
                           )
```

**Data frame - FID**

```
structure(list(Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), Month = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
"November", "December"), class = "factor"), Monsoon = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("First_Inter_Monssoon", "North_Monsoon", 
"Second_Inter_Monsoon", "South_Monsson"), class = "factor"), 
    Frequency = c(36, 28, 39, 46, 5, 0, 0, 22, 10, 15, 8, 
    33, 33, 29, 31, 23, 8, 9, 7, 40, 41, 41, 30, 30, 44, 37, 
    41, 42, 20, 0, 7, 27, 35, 27, 43, 38), Days = c(31, 
    28, 31, 30, 6, 0, 0, 29, 15, 29, 29, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 
    7, 0, 7, 30, 30, 31, 30, 27, 31, 28, 30, 30, 21, 0, 7, 26, 
    29, 27, 29, 29)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is when you use `update_role(contains("id"), Year, Month, Monsoon, Days, new_role = "id vars")`, you update the role of all the variables such as `Year`, `Month`, `Monsoon`, etc to be `"id vars"` and then they aren't predictors anymore. When the recipe moves to the next preprocessing steps, it finds that there aren't any predictors at all.

If you want to use those variables as predictors, then leave their roles as is and do not change them to something else like `"id vars"`:

```r
library(tidymodels) 
library(baguette) # bagged trees

fid_df <- structure(list(Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
                                  2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
                                  2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                  2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), Month = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
                                                                                                 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("January", "February", "March", 
                                                                                                                                    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
                                                                                                                                    "November", "December"), class = "factor"), Monsoon = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("First_Inter_Monssoon", "North_Monsoon", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Second_Inter_Monsoon", "South_Monsson"), class = "factor"), 
                         Frequency = c(36, 28, 39, 46, 5, 0, 0, 22, 10, 15, 8, 
                                       33, 33, 29, 31, 23, 8, 9, 7, 40, 41, 41, 30, 30, 44, 37, 
                                       41, 42, 20, 0, 7, 27, 35, 27, 43, 38), Days = c(31, 
                                                                                       28, 31, 30, 6, 0, 0, 29, 15, 29, 29, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 
                                                                                       7, 0, 7, 30, 30, 31, 30, 27, 31, 28, 30, 30, 21, 0, 7, 26, 
                                                                                       29, 27, 29, 29)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")

# split the data
fid_split <- initial_split(fid_df)

# extract the training data
fid_train <- training(fid_split)

# resample the data with 10-fold cross-validation (10-fold by default)
cv <- vfold_cv(fid_train)

##Preprocessing

rec <- recipe(Frequency ~ ., data = fid_df) %>% 
  step_nzv(all_predictors(), freq_cut = 0, unique_cut = 0) %>% # remove variables with zero variances
  step_novel(all_nominal()) %>% # prepares test data to handle previously unseen factor levels 
  step_medianimpute(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes(), -has_role("id vars"))  %>% # replaces missing numeric observations with the median
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -has_role("id vars")) # dummy codes categorical variables


rf_spec <- rand_forest(trees = 1e3) %>%
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "permutation") %>% 
  set_mode("regression")

wflow_rf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(rf_spec) %>% 
  add_recipe(rec)

fit_resamples(
  wflow_rf,
  cv,
  metrics = metric_set(rmse, rsq),
  control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rlang'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     %@%, as_function, flatten, flatten_chr, flatten_dbl, flatten_int,
#>     flatten_lgl, flatten_raw, invoke, list_along, modify, prepend,
#>     splice
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'vctrs'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tibble':
#> 
#>     data_frame
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     data_frame
#> # Resampling results
#> # 10-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    splits         id     .metrics         .notes           .predictions    
#>    <list>         <chr>  <list>           <list>           <list>          
#>  1 <split [24/3]> Fold01 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 4]>
#>  2 <split [24/3]> Fold02 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 4]>
#>  3 <split [24/3]> Fold03 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 4]>
#>  4 <split [24/3]> Fold04 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 4]>
#>  5 <split [24/3]> Fold05 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 4]>
#>  6 <split [24/3]> Fold06 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 4]>
#>  7 <split [24/3]> Fold07 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]> <tibble [3 × 4]>
#>  8 <split [25/2]> Fold08 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]> <tibble [2 × 4]>
#>  9 <split [25/2]> Fold09 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]> <tibble [2 × 4]>
#> 10 <split [25/2]> Fold10 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 1]> <tibble [2 × 4]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Comment: Dear Julia. Thank you so much for answering my question, I really appreciate it! I have been working on adding a general linear model for model comparisons with the decision trees to find the model of best fit. Would it be possible to please ask if I have done this correctly? The glm model can be found in this question below! I am confused with tuning the model. Thank you in advance if you don't think I am oversteping.

Comment: Here's the question involving the glm model: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64892060/tidymodel-package-general-linear-models-glm-and-decision-tree-bagged-trees

Comment: I will edit the glm question based on your corrections with this particular question. Many thanks in advance if you can lead me down the right path. I am not an advanced R coder, so I am trying my best. Many thanks in advance